# How to get cumulated values from timestamped arrays in even intervals [PYTHON]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, timestamp, scipy

I have a numpy array with timestamps in seconds

For example, this array named `a`:

```
a = np.array(10,95,99,100,250)
```

Then I have an array `b` which gives me the amount of shares that come in corresponding to the timestamps in a:

```
b = np.array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to find the number of shares that come in every minute, is there a quick way of doing this without iterating through the whole array?

- 10-70: 1 share came in
- 70-130: 9 shares came in
- 130-190: 0 shares came in
- 190 - 250: 5 shares came in

e.g.:

```
result = [1,9,0,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

These's indeed a quick and painless way to do this:

```
bins = np.arange(10, 250+1, 60)
result, _ = np.histogram(a, bins, weights=b)
```